# XAML - recursive game logic

Tags: c#, xaml

I am working on small game now and the logic works with `Attack` method from ModelView class which it should be called every 1 second and also needs to beggin `OnStartup` . How should i implement it?

```
public class MainModelView: BaseViewModel
{
    private ICommand attack;

    public MainModelView()
    {
    }

    public ICommand Attack
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.attack == null)
            {
                this.attack = new RelayCommand(this.PerformAttack);
            }

            return this.attack;
        }
    }

    private void PerformAttack(object obj);
}
```

And XAML

```
<Window x:Class="ConsoleHeroes.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:lib="clr-namespace:ConsoleHeroes.ViewModels"
        Title="ConsoleHeroes" Width="1200" Height="700" Name="Main">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <lib:MainModelView/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: DispatcherTimer will get you started : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Tried recursion in the method after finishing but that cause stackoverflow lol, also trying something from the App.xaml.cs before the window initialization but dont worked again.

Comment: @Sievajet Reading it atm thanks.